# Android: create a drawable that shows two lines of text one above the other in different fonts and sizes?

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-drawable, floating-action-button

I want to create a single drawable that shows two lines of text, one above the other. Each line of text has to be in it's own typeface and textsize and it has to create a single drawable because I want to then set it as the drawable for a floating action button.

```
private void updateFloatingButtonText(String headlineText, String subHeadlineText, FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton) {

    int headlineTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.headlineTextSize);
    int subheadlineTextSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.subheadlineTextSize);

    Spannable spannableStringHeadline = new SpannableString(headlineText);
    Spannable spannableStringSubheadline = new SpannableString(subHeadlineText);

    CustomTypefaceSpan boldSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan("FontOne", FontCache.get("FontOne.ttf", this));
    CustomTypefaceSpan regularSpan = new CustomTypefaceSpan("FontTwo", FontCache.get("FontTwo.ttf", this));

    // set typeface headline
    spannableStringHeadline.setSpan(regularSpan, 0,
            headlineText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    );


    // set typeface subtitle
    spannableStringSubheadline.setSpan(boldSpan, 0,
            subHeadlineText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    );

       // set text size headline
    spannableStringHeadline.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(headlineTextSize), 0,
            headlineText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    );

     // set text size subline
    spannableStringSubheadline.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(subheadlineTextSize), 0,
            subHeadlineText.length(), Spanned.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE
    );

    String finalString = TextUtils.concat(spannableStringHeadline, "\n", spannableStringSubheadline);

    floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable([put the resulting drawable here]);
}
```

I've written this method that creates a single string formatted exactly the way that I need it, but I still have the issue of creating a drawable out of it.

I've tried to use this third party library, but although it displays the text in the correct typefaces it doesn't change the textsize of the lines of text.

https://github.com/devunwired/textdrawable

Is there a trivial (or nontrivial) way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by creating a new class that looks like this:

```
public class TextToDrawable extends Drawable {

    private String headlineText = "";
    private String subHeadlineText = "";
    private final TextPaint headlinePaint = new TextPaint();
    private final TextPaint subHeadlinePaint = new TextPaint();

    public TextToDrawable(Context context, String headlineText, String subHeadlineText) {

        this.headlineText = headlineText;
        headlinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        headlinePaint.setTypeface(FontCache.get("FontA.ttf", context));
        headlinePaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.headlineTextSize));
        headlinePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white));
        headlinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        headlinePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);

        this.subHeadlineText = subHeadlineText;
        subHeadlinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        subHeadlinePaint.setTypeface(FontCache.get("FontB.ttf", context));
        subHeadlinePaint.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.subheadlineTextSize));
        subHeadlinePaint.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.white));
        subHeadlinePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        subHeadlinePaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

        Rect headlineWidth = new Rect();
        Rect subheadlineWidth = new Rect();

        headlinePaint.getTextBounds(headlineText, 0, headlineText.length(), headlineWidth);
        subHeadlinePaint.getTextBounds(subHeadlineText, 0, subHeadlineText.length(), subheadlineWidth);

        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        headlinePaint.getTextBounds(headlineText, 0, headlineText.length(), bounds);
        int x = getBounds().width() / 2 - (headlineWidth.width()/2);
        int y = (getBounds().height() / 2);

        canvas.drawText(headlineText, x, y, headlinePaint);

        x = getBounds().width()/2 - (subheadlineWidth.width()/2);
        y += headlinePaint.getFontSpacing();

        canvas.drawText(subHeadlineText, x, y, subHeadlinePaint);

    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter colorFilter) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Then using the new class like this:

```
mFloatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(new TextToDrawable(this, "Headline", "Subheadline"));
```

This isn't a great solution because it only supports two lines of text - there's nothing dynamic going on here. However, I suppose it would be fairly easy to rewrite to support even more lines and more fonts and it solves the current problem.